# prisma.create query with FK reference

Tags: mysql, prisma

I'm struggling to find the reference to this in the prisma documentation

I have 2 tables

```
User(
    Id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
) 
Post(
    Id INT,
    Title VARCHAR(255), 
    Creator INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY Creator REFERENCES User(Id)
)
```

When I attempt to create a new post with the following

```js
prisma.post.create({
    data: {
        Title: 'my post',
        Creator: 1
    }
})
```

The query doesn't recognize the FK as I'm guessing that it isn't being satisfied by my approach, and therefore fails.

What is the correct method to do this in prisma?

Answer (score 0):

By more closely reading the error message I was able to resolve this as shown below.

```js
prisma.post.create({
    data: {
        Title: 'my post',
        user: {
            connect:{Id: 1}
        }
    }
})
```